# Bootstrap Carousel has no slide animation in Chrome but works fine in Edge

Tags: html, animation, bootstrap-4

I have no idea what i am doing wrong. The slide i have here works just great on edge, but not on chrome. What am i missing?
And on the side note; image-responsive clsas for images makes them responsive on chrome but not on edge. I have a feeling that these issues are coraleted. Can they?

Edit: Slide animation is missing in firefox too!

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  

<div class="slide">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="kampanyainfo px-0">
                <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <div class="carousel-inner">
                        <div class="carousel-item active">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1517994112540-009c47ea476b?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="First slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1494905998402-395d579af36f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Second slide">
                        </div>
                        <div class="carousel-item">
                            <img class="d-block w-100" src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1503736334956-4c8f8e92946d?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9" alt="Third slide">
                        </div>
                    </div> 
                    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
                        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>        


  
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: It works on my chrome :/

Comment: Well damn. I mean yeah, i figured that its because of something on my end but no idea what it is.

Comment: Perhaps it's a simple setting in your browser or OS? `prefers-reduced-motion` media query is active as far as I remember correctly. [article](https://developer.paciellogroup.com/blog/2019/05/short-note-on-prefers-reduced-motion-and-puzzled-windows-users/)